# Qt5Quickd.lib(Qt5Quickd.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'

Tags: c++, windows, qt, makefile, qmake

I'm trying to build Qt application with command line rather than QtCreator GUI tools. I'm using *Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017* by running these commands:

```sh
"C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" ..\qt3dsceneeditor.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
"C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" -f ../../build-qt3dsceneeditor-Desktop_Qt_5_13_0_MSVC2017_64bit-Debug/Makefile qmake_all
"C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
```

The build process is all fine until the `link` stage which runs into this error:

```sh
link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /DLL /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\editorlib.dll @C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\editorlib.dll.13948.102703.jom
Qt5Quickd.lib(Qt5Quickd.dll) : fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
jom: C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\scripts\editorlib\Makefile.Debug [debug\editorlib.dll] Error 1112
jom: C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\scripts\editorlib\Makefile [debug] Error 2
jom: C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\scripts\Makefile [sub-editorlib-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

I have studied the similar errors reported by others, mentioning that I need to change Visual Studio configuration. But In my case, I'm not using VS GUI. How can I change configuration on *Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017*?

Also I appreciate if somebody can introduce a good guide for building Qt applications with command-line tools rather than QtCreator GUI!

As suggested by @code_fodder, I'm looking at QtCreator logs. QtCreator does compiling/linking without any error:

[image: QtCreator is fine]

The error on command-line is:

[image: Command line runs into error]

I also tried using `nmake` rather than `jom` which runs into the same error:

```sh
echo Setting up environment for Qt usage...
set PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\bin;%PATH%
echo --------------------------------------
mkdir C:\Users\me\repos\build
cd C:\Users\me\repos\build\
qmake.exe -makefile C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\qt3dsceneeditor.pro
nmake /u /f Makefile
```

---

### UPDATE

On Linux, I don't run into such error. On openSUSE Leap 15.1, this script works just fine:

```sh
#!/bin/sh 

export PATH=~/Qt5.13.0/5.13.0/gcc_64/bin/:$PATH 
mkdir build 
cd build 
qmake ../qt3dsceneeditor.pro -spec linux-icc-64 CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler 
make -j4
```

Comment: Your question seems to imply that this works through the Qt Creator (GUI) project? - essentially Qt Creator still calls qmake (if needed), you should be able to see the output of what Qt Creator is doing - look at the compile output tab (you can tell qt creator to show this if you don't have it open already). But are you sure that you want `-spec win32-msvc`? it looks like the Qt libraries you have are 64-bit libraries - do you have the 32 bit libraries?

Comment: @code_fodder Thanks. Right, I look at compile coutput tab and see QtCreator logs. For some reason, Qt Creator is using `-spec win32-msvc` options: `13:24:01: Starting: "C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\qt3dsceneeditor.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"`

Comment: hmm... I would suggest that your "environment" is different to the one used in Qt Creator. I am a bit rusty on Qt as I have not been using it for a while, but I think you can look at the enironment variables set in the Qt Creator GUI - They may be different to the ones you are using on the command line. Now, I can't recall if you can get a command-prompt via Qt Creator GUI - but you can change the build settings to run a command line instead of automatically calling qmake etc... So in there you can test your manual command + params and see if it works in Qt Creator. After that (which should...

Comment: ...work you will probably need to go through the paths and such to find what is different. You are probably looking for paths that specifiy where the Qt Libraries are in and set them up in your cmd shell. It may be worth having a script to do this to start with (sets the env vars and then call cmd.exe) and you can then copy the environment from Qt GUI...

Comment: @code_fodder Thanks. Tha'ts right, I'm going to work on environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem got resolved by this script:

```sh
set PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\5.13.0\msvc2017_64\bin;%PATH%
set PATH=C:\Qt\Qt5.13.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin;%PATH%
mkdir C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\scripts\build-deploy\temp
cd C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\scripts\build-deploy\temp
qmake.exe C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\qt3dsceneeditor.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=qtquickcompiler"
jom.exe qmake_all
jom.exe
```

I'm not sure which modification resolved the problem.

---

Also in debug mode the build is fine:

```sh
qmake.exe C:\Users\me\repos\qt3d-editor\qt3dsceneeditor.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
```

---

I run the scripts on x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017:

[image: x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2017]